# Prepared statement inside or outside a try/cach?

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch, prepared-statement

My doubt is whether the prepared statement should be inside or outside a try/catch block.

(this is an example method from my User class)

Should I do this?

```
public function getEmail( $id_user ) {
  $this->_sql = 'SELECT Email FROM '.TBL_USERS.' WHERE IdUser = :id_user';
  $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($this->_sql);
  try {
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchObject();
    if (is_object($row)) {
      return $row->Email;
    }
    return NULL;
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw $e;
  }  
}
```

or this?

```
public function getEmail( $id_user ) {
  $this->_sql = 'SELECT Email FROM '.TBL_USERS.' WHERE IdUser = :id_user';
  try {
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($this->_sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchObject();
    if (is_object($row)) {
      return $row->Email;
    }
    return NULL;
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

Comment: always prepare inside the `try`. sql syntax errors can/will sneak through.

Comment: If you're not going to do anything *meaningful* with the exception then don't catch it at all. Re-throwing the exception like that is just going to make the stack trace more difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepare() method can potentially throw a PDOException so you should include the call to prepare inside of the try block.
However in both of the examples you're just re-throwing the exception. Unless you're actually going to handle the exception inside of the catch block the effect will be the same.